# Is it OK to use "and" before "gave" in this sentence?

Tags: sentence-construction

> Few minutes later, Johnson met by Charlie, who bought two vinyl
>   records with him **and gave** to Johnson.

Charlie bought two vinyl records with him & gave to Johnson.

Is it OK to use and before gave in this sentence?

Comment: Is "him" Johnson? Also you need to explain why you think "and before gave" might be a problem.

Comment: Yes, **him** is **Johnson** here, I feel it is wrong to put "and" before "gave" in above sentence.

Answer (score 2):

> Few minutes later, Johnson met by Charlie, who bought two vinyl
>   records with him and gave to Johnson

To answer your specific question, Yes, but you need to say 'them' or 'one' after 'gave' for it to make sense. "...and gave **them** to Johnson." otherwise, 'gave' is just hanging there, a verb with nothing to act upon.

Here's how I would rephrase this:

**A** *f*ew minutes later, Johnson **was** met by Charlie, who b**r**ought two vinyl records with **him, which he** gave to Johnson.

The problem here is that your sentence isn't really clear. I think you meant 'brought' and not 'bought'. Brought would make sense if you meant that he had the records with him when he met with Charlie. If you meant that they purchased two vinyl records together, then you'd use 'bought'.  It's still a bit cumbersome, but it takes care of the incorrect bits.

Comment: or: and gave them to Johnson. I would stress the need for an object with give. I would also remove the highlight from the question and highlight your correct sentence.